# Paypal MPL library is not working on Android 4.0

Tags: android, exception, paypal

Paypal MPL library is not working on Android 4.0 . It is showing an error message after login.
`"Please make sure all fields have been entered"`.However the same library is working fine with Android 2.3.

Exception printed in Logs were as follows:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT SessionToken=6iY...@1:73 in java.io.InputStreamReader@416b9388)
```

Please help me in solving this problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is most likely a coding issue. Is your MPL the latest version (build 44 on Android)? I ran the SimpleDemo coming with MPL on Android 4.1.2 and didn't have a problem. Please compare the sample code to your code.

For your information a new build of MPL is coming out to fix a certificate issue. It's build 45 on Android. You may find it here:

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

(official notification from PayPal is on the way but the link should be this).

John